# JavaScript recursive access in JSON object and rename some key-values on children

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, recursion

I am trying to iterate a JSON object structure which looks like this.

```js
    {
    "id": 1,
    "recursoId": {
        "id": 1,
        "tipoRecurso": {
            "id": 5,
            "nombre": "Base de datos PostgreSQL",
            "icono": "fas fa-database"
        },
        "alias": "Base de datos Producción (Retama)",
        "nombre": "Retama",
        "propietario": {
            "id": 4,
            "nombre": "Sistemas"
        },
        "servicio012": false
    },
    "ip": "120",
    "port": "1234",
    "parent": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "recursoId": {
                "id": 2,
                "tipoRecurso": {
                    "id": 5,
                    "nombre": "Base de datos PostgreSQL",
                    "icono": "fas fa-database"
                },
                "alias": "Base de datos Preproducción (Faya)",
                "nombre": "Faya",
                "propietario": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "nombre": "Sistemas"
                },
                "servicio012": false
            },
            "ip": "101",
            "port": "101",
            "parent": null,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "recursoId": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "tipoRecurso": {
                            "id": 3,
                            "nombre": "Servidor aplicaciones Tomcat",
                            "icono": "fas fa-database"
                        },
                        "alias": "Servidor Producción (Tacoronte2)",
                        "nombre": "Tacoronte2",
                        "propietario": {
                            "id": 4,
                            "nombre": "Sistemas"
                        },
                        "servicio012": false
                    },
                    "ip": "103",
                    "port": "103",
                    "parent": null,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 8,
                            "recursoId": {
                                "id": 8,
                                "tipoRecurso": {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "nombre": "Aplicación",
                                    "icono": "fas fa-terminal"
                                },
                                "alias": "Inicio",
                                "nombre": "Inicio",
                                "propietario": {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "nombre": "Formación"
                                },
                                "servicio012": true
                            },
                            "ip": "107",
                            "port": "107",
                            "parent": null,
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 9,
                            "recursoId": {
                                "id": 8,
                                "tipoRecurso": {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "nombre": "Aplicación",
                                    "icono": "fas fa-terminal"
                                },
                                "alias": "Inicio",
                                "nombre": "Inicio",
                                "propietario": {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "nombre": "Formación"
                                },
                                "servicio012": true
                            },
                            "ip": "108",
                            "port": "108",
                            "parent": null,
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "recursoId": {
                        "id": 5,
                        "tipoRecurso": {
                            "id": 5,
                            "nombre": "Base de datos PostgreSQL",
                            "icono": "fas fa-database"
                        },
                        "alias": "Base de datos Preproducción (Faya)",
                        "nombre": "Tejina",
                        "propietario": {
                            "id": 4,
                            "nombre": "Sistemas"
                        },
                        "servicio012": true
                    },
                    "ip": "104",
                    "port": "104",
                    "parent": null,
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "recursoId": {
                "id": 3,
                "tipoRecurso": {
                    "id": 5,
                    "nombre": "Base de datos PostgreSQL",
                    "icono": "fas fa-database"
                },
                "alias": "Base de datos Desarrollo (Tabaiba)",
                "nombre": "Tabaiba",
                "propietario": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "nombre": "Sistemas"
                },
                "servicio012": false
            },
            "ip": "102",
            "port": "102",
            "parent": null,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "recursoId": {
                        "id": 6,
                        "tipoRecurso": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "nombre": "Aplicación",
                            "icono": "fas fa-terminal"
                        },
                        "alias": "Buzón",
                        "nombre": "Buzon",
                        "propietario": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "nombre": "Formación"
                        },
                        "servicio012": false
                    },
                    "ip": "105",
                    "port": "105",
                    "parent": null,
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "recursoId": {
                        "id": 7,
                        "tipoRecurso": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "nombre": "Aplicación",
                            "icono": "fas fa-terminal"
                        },
                        "alias": "Estadísticas",
                        "nombre": "Estadisticas",
                        "propietario": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "nombre": "Formación"
                        },
                        "servicio012": true
                    },
                    "ip": "106",
                    "port": "106",
                    "parent": null,
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So it's a tree-like child-parent relation. Every node has a unique ID. I'm triying to iterate along the complete object with a recursive function but i have some problems with the children.

This is my code where "instancias" is the complete object

```js
jsonAdapter(instancias: any) {
    Object.entries(instancias).forEach((entry) => {
      const [key, value] = entry;
      if (key === 'recursoId') {
        Object.entries(value).forEach((recursoIdEntry) => {
          const [key, value] = recursoIdEntry;
          if (key === 'tipoRecurso') {
            Object.entries(value).forEach((tipoRecursoEntry) => {
              const [key, value] = tipoRecursoEntry;
            })
          }
          if (key === 'propietario') {
            Object.entries(value).forEach((propietarioEntry) => {
              const [key, value] = propietarioEntry;
            })
          }
        })
      }
      if ((key === 'children') && value) {
        for (let i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
          this.jsonAdapter(value[i]);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I execute my code and it returns the first branch of the tree correctly. But after that  the function always returns undefined (Always enter to the if too). II'm not sure how to fix this. Thank you!.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: Right now im only triying to print it to see if its working, something like this on the last if.

```console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);

```
and see all the json.

Comment: rename what to what? (please state clearly).

Comment: I want to manipulate the Keys, so i want to delete some of them (servicio012) for example and rename anothers, nombre-> label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function "leaves" recursively iterates leaf key/values, passing the containing object for context. As an example here, the caller uses it to rename all of the "nombre" props to "renamed_nombre".

```js
function leaves(obj, callback) {
  for (let property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && obj[property] != null) {
      if (typeof obj[property] === 'object') {
        leaves(obj[property], callback);
      } else if (typeof obj[property] === 'array') {
        for (let i = 0; i < obj[property].length; i++) {
          leaves(obj[property][i], callback);
        }
      } else {
        callback(obj, property, obj[property])
      }
    }
  }
}

let bigObject = getBigObject()
leaves(bigObject, (object, key, value) => {
  if (key === 'nombre') {
    object.renamed_nombre = value
    delete object[key]
  }
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(bigObject, null, 4))


function getBigObject() {
  return {
    "id": 1,
    "recursoId": {
      "id": 1,
      "tipoRecurso": {
        "id": 5,
        "nombre": "Base de datos PostgreSQL",
        "icono": "fas fa-database"
      },
      "alias": "Base de datos Producción (Retama)",
      "nombre": "Retama",
      "propietario": {
        "id": 4,
        "nombre": "Sistemas"
      },
      "servicio012": false
    },
    "ip": "120",
    "port": "1234",
    "parent": null,
    "children": [{
        "id": 2,
        "recursoId": {
          "id": 2,
          "tipoRecurso": {
            "id": 5,
            "nombre": "Base de datos PostgreSQL",
            "icono": "fas fa-database"
          },
          "alias": "Base de datos Preproducción (Faya)",
          "nombre": "Faya",
          "propietario": {
            "id": 4,
            "nombre": "Sistemas"
          },
          "servicio012": false
        },
        "ip": "101",
        "port": "101",
        "parent": null,
        "children": [{
            "id": 4,
            "recursoId": {
              "id": 4,
              "tipoRecurso": {
                "id": 3,
                "nombre": "Servidor aplicaciones Tomcat",
                "icono": "fas fa-database"
              },
              "alias": "Servidor Producción (Tacoronte2)",
              "nombre": "Tacoronte2",
              "propietario": {
                "id": 4,
                "nombre": "Sistemas"
              },
              "servicio012": false
            },
            "ip": "103",
            "port": "103",
            "parent": null,
            "children": [{
                "id": 8,
                "recursoId": {
                  "id": 8,
                  "tipoRecurso": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "nombre": "Aplicación",
                    "icono": "fas fa-terminal"
                  },
                  "alias": "Inicio",
                  "nombre": "Inicio",
                  "propietario": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "nombre": "Formación"
                  },
                  "servicio012": true
                },
                "ip": "107",
                "port": "107",
                "parent": null,
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": 9,
                "recursoId": {
                  "id": 8,
                  "tipoRecurso": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "nombre": "Aplicación",
                    "icono": "fas fa-terminal"
                  },
                  "alias": "Inicio",
                  "nombre": "Inicio",
                  "propietario": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "nombre": "Formación"
                  },
                  "servicio012": true
                },
                "ip": "108",
                "port": "108",
                "parent": null,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "recursoId": {
              "id": 5,
              "tipoRecurso": {
                "id": 5,
                "nombre": "Base de datos PostgreSQL",
                "icono": "fas fa-database"
              },
              "alias": "Base de datos Preproducción (Faya)",
              "nombre": "Tejina",
              "propietario": {
                "id": 4,
                "nombre": "Sistemas"
              },
              "servicio012": true
            },
            "ip": "104",
            "port": "104",
            "parent": null,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "recursoId": {
          "id": 3,
          "tipoRecurso": {
            "id": 5,
            "nombre": "Base de datos PostgreSQL",
            "icono": "fas fa-database"
          },
          "alias": "Base de datos Desarrollo (Tabaiba)",
          "nombre": "Tabaiba",
          "propietario": {
            "id": 4,
            "nombre": "Sistemas"
          },
          "servicio012": false
        },
        "ip": "102",
        "port": "102",
        "parent": null,
        "children": [{
            "id": 6,
            "recursoId": {
              "id": 6,
              "tipoRecurso": {
                "id": 1,
                "nombre": "Aplicación",
                "icono": "fas fa-terminal"
              },
              "alias": "Buzón",
              "nombre": "Buzon",
              "propietario": {
                "id": 1,
                "nombre": "Formación"
              },
              "servicio012": false
            },
            "ip": "105",
            "port": "105",
            "parent": null,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 7,
            "recursoId": {
              "id": 7,
              "tipoRecurso": {
                "id": 1,
                "nombre": "Aplicación",
                "icono": "fas fa-terminal"
              },
              "alias": "Estadísticas",
              "nombre": "Estadisticas",
              "propietario": {
                "id": 1,
                "nombre": "Formación"
              },
              "servicio012": true
            },
            "ip": "106",
            "port": "106",
            "parent": null,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem you have is in the last `if` statement, where you have a loop using `entry.length` which will **always return 2** since each entry has a key and value pair. Even if children is empty, entry equals `["children", []]` and its length is 2. You should use value.length instead as below:

```
if ((key === 'children') && value) {
    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        this.jsonAdapter(value[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the problems is the function always enters the if i dont know why. However im gonna try that.